# Confusion in print method in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Whenever I try to print the char arrays to the console, I'm getting the result in integer format, but whenever I try to print integer arrays to the console, I'm getting the result in hashcode format. Could anyone please tell me why?

```
char[] arr={'4','5','6'};
System.out.println(arr); //456

int[] arr={4,5,6};
System.out.println(arr) //[I@3e25a5]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`java.io.PrintStream` (the class of `System.out`) has a special [`print`-method for `char[]`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28char[]%29), but not for `int[]`. So for the `char[]`, this special method is used, while `int[]` is printed via the generic version, which prints the hashcode (or, to be more precise, the result of `String.valueOf()` called with the object as parameter).

Answer (score 3):

Simply because there's no method for which handles `int[]` specially. It would be printed by [`String#valueOf()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) instead which implicitly calls [`Object#toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). If the `Object#toString()` isn't overridden in the given object type, then the following will get printed (as per the aforelinked API).

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The `int[]` class has a name of `[I`.

To achieve what you want, you need [`Arrays#toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) instead:

```
int[] arr = {4, 5, 6};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the character array is just used like a string (which is in fact also just an array of characters).

In the second it has no overload for the type of integer array and just prints out the object reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first one is treated as a CharSequence... like a String.